# Video Buffering implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-5

i have implemented `Custom Video Player` feature in my Application that will used to play online videos now i want to implement video buffering feature i am searching for it but not getting proper solution.

So can anyone guide me please.

Answer (score 3):

look into the AVPlayer + AVPlayerLayer classes.

load AVPlayer with the URL of the video.

give it some time to buffer the video before calling the playing method, maybe like this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(play:) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think **MPMoviePlayerController** by default supports the streaming feature. Why don't you try that.